# Is there a way to unit test ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate without using Thread.sleep?

Tags: java, unit-testing, scheduledexecutorservice

I would like to unit test a class that executes a task using ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate, and I can't find a way to "schedule" multiple runs of the task in a unit test without using Thread.sleep, which is slow and not as precise as I'd like. Is there any way to pass a mocked time reference to the executor service or other workarounds to simulate the passage of time?

Comment: You could write your own ScheduledExecutorService implementation, and add some extra methods to it like "fireEventsBefore(time)". Would that work for you?

Comment: I guess it's the wrong way to go, you should unit test the logic that is getting executed at a fixed rate, and you should trust in the standard library's ability of doing it's work right. it's not up to you to test that.

Comment: The part I want to test here is how I handle errors that occur with the ScheduledExecutorService, such as does the runnable continue to be executed after one execution throws an error, which is not default functionality for the class.

Answer (score 1):

*Unit Tests* verify behavior of **your code** in isolation from its dependencies.

The implementations of `ScheduledExecutorService` are provided by the JVM and therefore not your code, but a *dependency* that must be replaced with a *test double* while unittesting your code. (There might be a valid setup for a test that needs the `ScheduledExecutorService` implementation to be executed, but this is not a *unit test* then.)

So in case you are writing a unit test (and not some other kind of test as i.e. *integration tests*, that happens to be using the *JUnit framwork*)  you should create a **mock**  for the `ScheduledExecutorService` interface using a *mocking framework* (like [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) or alike) and verify that *your code* calls the desired method on the mock.

To enable your test for this verification you should *inject* the implementation of  `ScheduledExecutorService` interface into your code (preferably via [constructor injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/))  and not have your *unit under test* acquiring it itself, so that you have a *seam* at which you can exchange the real implementation of `ScheduledExecutorService` interface whith the mock for the purpose of unit testing.